# rails - gmap - set marker Icon on mouseOut depending of the default marker type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have a rails app with markers on a map (pink markers). When i mouseOn a marker on the sidebar, it change the color of the marker to BLUE (to follow on the map) and then when i mouseOut it comes back to the original color PINK. (works well)

But now i added an other color: when i CLICK on a marker (directly on the map or on the sidebar) the marker's color becomes grey. To allow my users to know that they have already check the information from that marker.

So if i mouseON now on a GREY marker from the sidebar, the marker become BLUE (normal) but if i mouseOut, il becomes pink and SHOULD STAY GREY.

if pink go back to pink
if grey go back to grey
How can i do that ? with a kind of attribute ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var raw_markers = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
    var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    function createSidebarLi(json){
      return json.sidebar;
      //return ("<li>" + json.titre + ' ' + json.address + "</li>");
    };

    function bindLiToMarker($li, marker){
      $li.on('click', function(){
        //handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
        marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
        marker.panTo();
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
      });
    };

    function bindLiToMarkerMouseOver($li, marker){
      $li.on('mouseover', function(){
        //handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
        marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
        marker.panTo();
        //google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
        marker.serviceObject.setIcon("http://198.100.149.26/lookn/markerBleu.png");
      });
    };

    function bindLiToMarkerMouseOut($li, marker){
      $li.on('mouseout', function(){
        //handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
        marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
        marker.panTo();
        //google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
        **if (marker.isVisited = true) {
          marker.serviceObject.setIcon("http://198.100.149.26/lookn/markerGris.png");
        } else {
          marker.serviceObject.setIcon("http://198.100.149.26/lookn/markerRose.png");
        }**
      });
    };

    function createSidebar(json_array){
      _.each(json_array, function(json){
        var $li = $( createSidebarLi(json) );
        $li.appendTo('#markers_list');
        bindLiToMarker($li, json.marker);
        bindLiToMarkerMouseOver($li, json.marker);
        bindLiToMarkerMouseOut($li, json.marker);
      });
    };

    function closeInfoWindow(handler){
      if(handler.currentInfowindow()) {
        handler.currentInfowindow().close();
      }
    }

    handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });
    //handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){

      var markers = handler.addMarkers(raw_markers);

      _.each(raw_markers, function(json, index){
        var marker = markers[index];
        json.marker = marker;
        //google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'mouseover', function(){
          //google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
        //});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
          marker.serviceObject.setIcon("http://198.100.149.26/lookn/markerGris.png");
          **marker.isVisited = true;**
        });
      });

      createSidebar(raw_markers);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.centerMapOnUser();

      google.maps.event.addListener(handler.getMap(), 'click', function(){ 
        closeInfoWindow(handler);
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      });

    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: You will have to save state of marker on click event, for example `marker.isVisited = true`. And check the state on mouseout event. If true, set gray icon. If not, set pink icon.

Comment: agreed, and dont forget you can put whatever properties you desire in the json, then you can adpat the logic

Comment: Thx for your help. I edited the code but it does not work withmarker.isVisited, whould i do something else ?

Comment: create a plunkr to get js help, its way easier for everybody,  you can fork this one for instance: http://plnkr.co/edit/yi8ctoiERs4K51iUZHZQ?p=info

Comment: I created one: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ItPPtUHDF9e5N4bMFoq?p=catalogue

Comment: ... ok now make it render something and illustrate the issue

Comment: illustrate the issue ? i tried your solution line 39 and 77 but it doesn't work

Comment: issue is your plunkr doesnt work at all

Comment: You want me to display the map and everything with plunkr ? it's a rails app with controllers and a lot of files needed to work. All i need to know is how to set a marker to be visited = true on my script

Comment: the point of a plunkr is to be minimalistic, you dont need help on your whole rails app do you?

Comment: no, but i have no idea how to make it "minimalistic" as you say. i would have to manually add markers and i dont know how. So thanks for your help, i'll search somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set visited = true on Click event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
          marker.serviceObject.set("isVisited", true);
        });
```

if visited = true mouseOut setIcon Grey, else setIcon Pink

```
function bindLiToMarkerMouseOut($li, marker){
      $li.on('mouseout', function(){
        marker.setMap(handler.getMap());
        if (marker.serviceObject.get("isVisited")) {
          marker.serviceObject.setIcon("path_to/greyMarker.png");
        } else {
          marker.serviceObject.setIcon("path_to/pinkMarker.png");
        };
      });
    };
```